# Angular2 - What's a good 'dist' folder size?

Tags: angular, firebase

**Note**

- I'm new to this and have just been 'blagging' my way through writing this code

**What I'm using**
 - Angular (using Angular Cli)
 - Firebase

**Issue / Concern**

- When I run 'ng build --watch' it creates a 'dist' folder. I've checked the size of the folder and it amounts to 11.4mb. This is what I need to upload to firebase.

**Questions**

- Is this a massive file size?
- How do I minify my files?
- Based on the image below, do the 'map' files need to be included? If not, how do I remove them?
- Any advice on running a build command for production?

[image]

Any help here would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: 'Acceptable' bundle size is a totally subjective metric - I'd personally say Angular is borderline incapable of generating an acceptably sized bundle, but that's just me... Either way, you shouldn't measure your bundle based on the development build - run `ng build -prod` to generate an optimized/minified build.

Comment: there are multiple factors in this, according to AddyOsamni Google Engineer file size must not be greater then to 2 MB (I read it some where). You can reduce size of these file via these tricks: Lazy Load Angular Routes, use GZIP compression and use `ng build -prod` with the latest `@angular/cli`

Comment: Thanks Both..I just tried ng build -prod and it produces errors that don't happen in ng build --watch. Are the map files required? Or is that something the prod command will remove? I'll look in to GZIP compression. 2MB? I'm on 11. That's a big difference :(

Comment: Good news. The prod command reduced it to 2.6m! Great news. I'll probably post a separate question regarding some code I needed to delete to get that to work. If I can figure out how to implement GZIP I think it'll be a good reduction

Comment: You don't need to worry about gzip. That's something that the server handles for you on the server side, and the browser handles for you on the client side. And no, a prod build will not produce map files (unless asked to), and no, you don't need to upload them to the server. All of this is perfectly well described in the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

too late here but anything about 10mb is not a good bundle for dist and kills the load time.
try to keep the size below 6mb if you have large files in your assets, explore the options to retrieve them from server.
concat es5 es2015 if they are derived separately from you the build.
run aot and build optimizers something like
ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer hope this helps.